# How many ways are there to define a vectorial subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

It is a very simple question, but I've been very confused with teachers defining the vectorial spaces in a lot of ways. Are the following ways to define a vectorial space correct? And are there more ways?

1. With equations $V=\{ \vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^3 : x_1+x_2-x_3=0; 4x_1+x_2-3x_3=2 \}$
2. With vectors itself $V=\{\vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^2 : \vec{x}=2\vec{i}-\vec{j}; \vec{i}=(1,0), \vec{j}=(0,1)\}$
3. With spans $V=span \{\vec{u_1},\dots,\vec{u_k}\}$

Note that I know that one can be transformed into the other but that isn't what I'm interested into.

Comment: I think you are confusing examples of vector spaces with an abstract definition.  There are lots and lots of examples of vector spaces...that's what makes them an interesting object of study.

Comment: Note that neither your first nor your second examples are vector spaces.  The first isn't because, if $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ satisfies $4x_1+x_2-3x_3=2$, then $(2x_1, 2x_2,2x_3)$ does not.  The second isn't because it consists of a single vector in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @lulu well yeah, just took 2 random examples. But it is true that with equations like I showed in 1 I can define a subspace, isn't it?

Comment: Your first example could be corrected by replacing the $2$ with a $0$.  I really don't know what you meant by your second example.

Comment: It's okay I got it now, a subspace is just too vast so there are many ways of defining it. Do you know any more recommended ways of learning linear algebra online?

Comment: I think the standard references are fine...the key point is to study lots of examples.  It's a subject that really, really depends on its examples.

Comment: @Aley20 I highly recommend Gilbert Strang's course on MITOpenCourseWare. It's excellent.